# How to add Beam cross section properties to imported mesh in Ansys?

Tags: beam, ansys, ansys-workbench

Ansys Workbench 17.1

I have a mesh that was imported from Abaqus into Ansys but the beam cross section data is missing. As a result the structural model omits the beam elements.

How do I access the beam cross section data in Ansys? I cant find any way to do it in the FE Modeler, Mechanical Model or Mesh modules so far.

EDIT: There appears to be no way of directly doing this in Ansys Work Bench or AIM. I had to write some code the alter the *inp files to include the missing information prior to importing to Ansys.

Comment: Did you import a 2d mesh or 3d? What do the Ansys help files suggest?

Comment: 3D, so far the Ansys help files have been of no help. I have only found reference to editing beam elements that were created with one of the Workbench modules. It seemed like this would be a fairly common feature like it is with every other FEA software I've used but oh no...